# repication of data from one domain to another

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

What would be the steps involved to join two Domain Controllers on different Domains?  The ultimate goal is to have user data replicated from one domain (abc domain) to another domain (xyz domain). The XYZ domain will be completely isolated from the abc domain from time to time.

Comment: Why do you want to replicate data? Just create a trust relationship between the domains. What's your user case?

Comment: I am unable to give to many specifics.  But the situation is that we need data from one network/domain ABC made available on a different domain XYZ. The larger network ABC will always be available but the smaller network XYZ will often be disconnect or isolated from ABC.  While XYZ is isolated users need access to there personal data that is normally on the Main network ABC. Presently the data only resides on the main network ABC, I am just not sure of how to join replicate the user data down to the isolated network.  I also am not sure that joining the two domains is the best course of action

Comment: 1. You can't join the domains together. 2. What is this user data exactly? 3. Why don't you schedule a robocopy job (or similar) to copy the data from ABC to XYZ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joe.  The user data is any files saved to their profile on the main network that the customer wishes to have available on the XYZ network.

Comment: You can just use some backup solutions and copy user data to one of the XYZ domain. Thus their data will be located in two networks.

Answer (score 0):

Creating cross-forest trusts in this situation sounds like a disaster waiting to happen (and cross-forest trusts are sometimes a disaster waiting to happen just in general).

It sounds like you just need to get some replication software keeping the two sites in sync, but you need to consider a bunch of different things:

- How often are you going to synchronize?
- How often does the data change on the ABC site?
- Do you ever change data on the XYZ site?
- What if two people change the same file on both sites between synchronization?
- Do you need to deal with file locks?

The outcome of questions like this are going to dictate the sorts of solutions you can implement. For example, you could probably just schedule a `robocopy` to run from ABC > XYZ once a day if you just have read-only not-often-changing data that doesn't need to be locked or protected.

But if you have a situation where you need to modify the data on both sites and synchronise them back, them something like [BitTorrent Sync](https://www.resilio.com/) might be what you need.

The problem you're facing is not unique by any stretch. If both sites were in the same domain then there's some really neat Windows features that might have worked (DFS-R, Branch Cache).

But we can't tell you the right way to solve your problem until you have scoped out what your problem actually is.